# Visual Studio Cordova App add plugin as optional feature

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am having an issue in publishing my app in **Google play** when I include some plugins like `cordova-plugin-geolocation` in my app, as it adds the following 2 permissions in my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

this causes an issue that ***some of the phones are not able to view the app*** in the google play as they tell me that `android.hardware.location.network` access is not compatible on those devices.

when I researched a bit more, I can see  that this can be avoided by converting `uses-permission` to `uses-feature` and setting the `android:required="false"` then I can handle it in my code as this is not a must have feature for me.

My issue is I am unable to find how to change this in my visual studio project. can someone please help me understand whats the way to fix this?

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

There is no way within VS to add contents to your Android projects manifest file. You will have to hand edit those, but beware that these changes would be over-written every time you build your project through VS. There are couple of ways you can workaround this -

- You can add post_build Cordova hook that would update the Manifest file.
- You can add a gulp task and hook this to MSBuild post_build event through VS.

SOak 
(PM - Microsoft)